# Adding content to fullcalendar event

Tags: events, fullcalendar, title

I have a problem with adding content to the event. I need a list of a few things in the body of the event (for each new line.) Is it even possible?

Another problem is that it doesn't show me at the top - end of the event, despite it's defined ...

I'm querying events from database and final result looks like this:

[{"id":305,"start":"2010-06-21 06:00:00","end":"2010-06-21 14:00:00","title":"D\u0142ug. zmiany: 8h Ilo\u015b\u0107 prac. : 1  *Grzegorz Nowak *Anna Nowak"}]

Answer (score 2):

not really sure what you're asking, but beyond using the title property, you can make arbitrary manipulations on events elements using the eventRender trigger:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/